# Statistical test for boundedness of mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I have $n$ i.i.d samples from a unknown distribution. I want to prove or disprove that the mean is bounded. Are there any statistical test for this hypothesis ?

Comment: Try googling "statistical test finite moments" (without quotes); however, a statistical test will not "prove" or "disprove" the hypothesis. One such test, described at free links on the [author's homepage](http://ifedotenkov.com/Publications.html) (including R and MATLAB code), is [Fedotenkov's boostrap test](http://ifedotenkov.com/Bootstrap_for_moments.pdf).

Comment: @r.e.s. That was very helpful. Could you add it as an answer so that I can vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling "statistical test finite moments" (without quotes); however, a statistical test will not "prove" or "disprove" the hypothesis. One such test, described at free links on the [author's homepage](http://ifedotenkov.com/Publications.html) (including R and MATLAB code), is [Fedotenkov's boostrap test](http://ifedotenkov.com/Bootstrap_for_moments.pdf). See also that author's [follow-up article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.836.5304&rep=rep1&type=pdf).